# Fetching fields which have values as array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My collection looks somewhat like this

```
{a:"foo", b:[10,20,30]}
{a:"boo", b:[15,25,35]}
{a:"abc", b:[10,40,50]}
{a:"xyz", b:[10,60,70]}
```

Now, I want to retrieve the entire array under a:"foo". How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 db.collection.find({"a":"foo"},{"b":1})
```

It'll return the b array.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({"a":"foo"})
```

Will return all object matching the criteria and then you can access to the "b" element of the results